# Issue on Adding Animation to jQuery toggleClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/6uNQL/1/) and let me know how I can add Animation / Speed or Duration to the following code

```
$("#ecolomodel").on("click",function(){
   $("#ecolomodelno").toggleClass("switchshow switchhiden");
   $("#ecolomodelyes").toggleClass("switchhiden switchshow");

});
```

using this mark up

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Switch</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="switch col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                <button id="ecolomodelno" class="btn btn-primary switchshow norightradius col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">No</button>
                <button id="ecolomodel" class="btn btn-primary noradius col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-8 col-xs-9">New Model</button>
                <button id="ecolomodelyes" class="btn btn-primary switchhiden noleftradius col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">Yes</button>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already tried something like

```
$("#ecolomodel").on("click",function(){
   $("#ecolomodelno").toggleClass("switchshow switchhiden", 6000);
   $("#ecolomodelyes").toggleClass("switchhiden switchshow", 6000);

});
```

but it didn't work!

Answer (score -1):

I think you really need to look into jQuery **[animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** and see how it works. It is a very simple function to use, and I find myself using it over and over again.

You can edit CSS directly. Try viewing and testing out some of the examples they have on their site.

Comment: Do a quick Google search for `CSS3 Animations`. They are extremely fast, and require less loading time than jQuery. Once you get the hang of them, they are super easy, and faster to write than jQuery :)

Comment: DOWNVOTER - Mind stating why...?

Comment: @Suffii - Don't worry mate, still trying to work on a solution haha